# Warning: N-API is an experimental feature and could change at any time

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

i'm very new to tensorflow.js. And while i ran my first program, i get this warning, "(node:4249) Warning: N-API is an experimental feature and could change at any time."
should i be worried about it or just ignore it? i don't want it to cause problems for me in future. What is N-API anyway?

Comment: Could you figure which part is causing the warning?

Comment: No. actually it's just one file that i tried running. should i share my code?

Comment: Could be helpful, yes

Answer (score 8):

You can ignore the warning for now.  It's talking about a library that bridges C++ code to Node.js code.  N-API is short for Node Addon API, and there is an awesome article on it [here](https://medium.com/@atulanand94/beginners-guide-to-writing-nodejs-addons-using-c-and-n-api-node-addon-api-9b3b718a9a7f)

Answer (score 4):

You can just hide the warning message using tag *--no-warnings* in your node launch:

```
node --no-warnings index.js
```